# Regex - Exclude pattern if a certain word appears after the desired word

Tags: python, regex

I want my regex to match the appearance of a certain word, except if it is followed by another specific word.

More specifically, I would like it to match `"union"` (in the sense of union or loyalty to a group, so it would not include words like `"reunion"`, i.e. with word boundaries at the beginning and end of the string) in all cases, except when the string says `"union europea"` (which is understood as an administration and does not appeal to a group in the same way).

Using the pattern `union\b` does not help, because it would also match the aforementioned sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
pattern = '\W(union)\W(?!europea)'
```

As pointed out by @Michael Ruth, you probably don't want to capture words other than `union`. So, with some [test data](https://regex101.com/r/IQXkoO/1):

```
unionize
union 
union europea
reunion
```

This pattern only captures `union` in the second case, (ie., it does not capture `reunion` or `unionize`. The `\W` are non-word characters, so additional letters (like from `reunion` and `unionize`) are not captured.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pattern = r'\bunion\b(?!\W*europea)'
```

`(?!\W*europea)` excludes matches where `union` is followed with nonword characters (if any) and then `europea` string.